# Two graphs with the same number of edges and vertices but not isomorphic?

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone give me an example of two graphs that have the same number of edges and vertices but is not isomorphic?

Comment: What did you try ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Any tree with $n$ vertices has exactly $n-1$ edges. Find two non-isomorphic trees with the same number of vertices, and you’re done.

Comment: Thanks Brian great answer!

Comment: @Rajinda: You’re welcome!